# ValueError in decoding json

Tags: python, regex, json

```
import json
import urllib
import re
import binascii 

def asciirepl(match):
  s = match.group()  
  return binascii.unhexlify(s[2:])  

query = 'google'
p = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q='+query+'&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de&client=te')
page = p.read()[2:-10] #As its returned as a function call

#To replace hex characters with ascii characters
p = re.compile(r'\\x(\w{2})')
ascii_string = p.sub(asciirepl, page)

#Now decoding cleaned json response
data = json.loads(ascii_string)
```

Running it, I get this error,

```
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ python2 define.py                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "define.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = json.loads(ascii_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 403 (char 403)
```

As far as I think, the json is without any errors as I recieved it from google's server. All, I did was removing hex characters. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is in line 1 column 403 (and around it)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker rather than wait for a response, I downloaded the json file from the URL implied by the code and inspected it myself. I suspect Izkata did something similar.

Comment: Indeed, I copied shadyabhi's code and ran it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decoding the \x escapes may produce " marks, which need to be re-escaped as they appear within "strings" encoded within the JSON data.

```
def asciirepl(match):
  chr = binascii.unhexlify(match.group()[2:])
  return '\\' + chr if chr in ('\\"') else chr
```

That still won't handle control characters; so you might instead want to convert the \x escapes into \u escapes, which are described in the JSON standard and parsed by the `json` module. This has the side benefit of being simpler :)

```
def asciirepl(match):
  return '\\u00' + match.group()[2:]
```

Comment: The Google folks probably shouldn't be using \x style escapes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Character 403 is the first embedded quote in "text" - this is invalid json:

```
{
   "type":"url",
   "text":"<a href="http://www.people-communicating.com/jargon-words.html">http://www.people-communicating.com/jargon-words.html</a>",
   "language":"en"
}
```

This is what was returned by the server - note, no embedded quotes:

```
{
    "type":"url",
    "text":"\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://www.people-communicating.com/jargon-words.html\\x22\\x3ehttp://www.people-communicating.com/jargon-words.html\\x3c/a\\x3e",
    "language":"en"
}
```

The best way to do this is to decode the json first, then de-hexify each string as you need it.

*EDIT*:  If that really is invalid JSON, as Karl Knechtel says in the comments, Google should be told their API is incorrect.  If Python's implementation is barfing on valid JSON, they should be told to fix it.  Whatever workaround you make, it should be easy to remove if this gets fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as described; `json.loads` chokes on the `\x##` style escapes because the json standard doesn't mention a `\x` sequence. However, it should be possible to make it work by first converting the `\x##` sequences to `\u00##` sequences.

Comment: I can't conceive of any way to read the information on www.json.org that would make it valid JSON. They probably didn't notice because Javascript itself does use such escapes. Many real-world parsers for JSON seem to be somewhat lax, though not to the extent that HTML parsers are ;)